# Enviar un token por http get

Tags: tokens, http-get

Intento pasar un token por httpClient para obtener los amigos, pero el token no se manda por el get

Usuario y contraseña para crear el token

```
 usuario = {
     email: 'to.murillo@duocuc.cl',
     password: 'Hola1234'
 }
```

En esta parte se guarda el token en la base de datos local

```
 guardarToken(token:any){
     localStorage.setItem('token',token)
     console.log('token guardado papito :'+localStorage.getItem("token"))
 };

/* localStorage.clear   : borrar todo de local sotrage bru */


borrarToken(){
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    console.log('token borrado papito :'+localStorage.getItem("token"))
}
```

Al ingresar al /Home se crea el token corectamente y se guarda en la base de datos local

```
login(){
      this.service.getTodoLogin(this.usuario).subscribe((info) => {
        info.email = this.usuario.email;
        info.password = this.usuario.password;
        this.token = info.data.token;
        this.service.borrarToken();
        this.service.guardarToken(this.token);
        if(localStorage.getItem('token')){
          this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        }
        //console.log(info);
        //console.log(info.data.token);
})


apiUrlAmigos = 'http://54.147.81.169:3006/api/friends? 
activated=1&friend_name=&friendrequeststatus_id=1';

getTodoAmigos(token:any):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrlAmigos, token);
}


apiUrlLogin  = 'http://54.147.81.169:3006/api/login';

getTodoLogin(usuario:any):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrlLogin, usuario);
}
```

al intentar cargar la api de amigos en la vista /amigos el token no me lo manda, el llamado al getTodoUsuario es enviado sin problemas y me devuelve a los usuarios, pero el cargar los amigos me saca el mensaje de error

```
ngOnInit() {

 this.token = localStorage.getItem('token');
 this.servicio.getTodoUsuario().subscribe((info)=>{
   this.usuario=info;
   this.usuarioPrueba=info.data;
   this.nombreUsuario=info.data[0].name;
   //console.log(info.data[0].name)
   //console.log(info.data[0])
   //console.log(info)
   console.log(this.usuarioPrueba)
 })
 /*El primero me carga sin problemas, pero el getTodoAmigos me trae error por el token*/
 this.servicio.getTodoAmigos(localStorage.getItem('token')).subscribe((infoAmigo)=>{
   this.tokenPruena = infoAmigo;
   console.log(this.tokenPruena);
 })
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En el momento en que envié esta pregunta la api estoy realizando unos cambios por lo que no esta activa, por eso si no les carga es por que estará disponible cuando termine de cambiar unas cosas

Comment: Revisa el concepto de `interceptors` Te ahorrarás bastantes líneas de código con una buena implementación de ello. Saludos :D